# can anyone explain this in English to me?

Tags: javascript

"whatYouTyped.parentNode;" can someone break this down to explain exactly what its doing thanks ?

```
function checkphone(whatYouTyped) {
var fieldset = whatYouTyped.parentNode;
var txt = whatYouTyped.value;
 if ( /^((\+\d{1,3}(-| )?\(?\d\)?(-| )?\d{1,5})|(\(?\d{2,6}\)?))(-| )?(\d{3,4})(-| )?(\d{4})(( x| ext)\d{1,5}){0,1}$/.test(txt)) {
    fieldset.className = "welldone";
    compphone=true;
} else {
    fieldset.className = "";
    compphone=false;
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the rest of the javascript code ?

Comment: parent node of what you typed.

Comment: Can you not just comment in any of these unclosed questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678674/javascript-form-validation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677548/form-validation - seems you need to take care of duplication here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to describe this in English without using some Jargon!

`whatYouTyped` is a variable which has been set to point to an element in the DOM tree.

`whatYouTyped.parentNode` is the parent element of this element.

To explain in more detail:

The DOM tree is the structure of the web page, as held in memory by the browser. Each tag in the HTML code is represented by an element in this tree structure.

Javascript is able to make direct access to any part of this tree, often by using the `getElelementById()` function (though there are plenty of other routes to getting at an element).

The `whatYouTyped` variable will likely have been set to point to a given element in the DOM tree using `getElementById()` or similar.

Part of the DOM tree structure is the ability to navigate between elements in the tree. `parentNode` is one of the methods that allows you to do this; it returns the element in the tree above the current one.

In this case, you might have HTML code that looks something like this:

```
<fieldset id='outerLayer'>
    <input type='text' id='whatYouTyped' value='This is what you typed' />
    <input type='text' id='somethingElse' value='This is something else' />
</fieldset>
```

Your code might have done something like this:

```
var whatYouTyped = document.getElementById('whatYouTyped');
```

As this point, the code you provided makes sense, because the `whatYouTyped` variable is now set to an element in the DOM tree. Asking for `whatYouTyped.parentNode` will give you the outerLayer element.

Looking at the code you've provided, it looks as if it is changing the class of the element wrapping the input field if the input passes validation. This would allow it to do something like change the background colour, or put a tick icon next to the field, or something like that if the user enters a valid string.

Hope that helps.

[EDIT]

I've changed the answer a bit in light of the edits to the question. The basic answer remains the same though.

Comment: so basically whatyoutyped is what the user typed in the txt box ?

Comment: @martin -- not quite. Technically, `whatYouTyped` is the whole`<input>` field, with all it's attributes, etc. The actual text that they user typed is `whatYouTyped.value`.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have something as follows:

```
<div><input type="text" onBlur="checkphone(this)"/></div>
```

Then `whatYouTyped.parentNode` will return reference to `div` that is the parent node of `input`.

Answer (score 0):

`whatYouTyped` must be a reference to a element.This statement is ceating a eference to the parent element(container) of `whatYouTyped` node.I guess before this statement there wd be a line like `whatYouTyped=document.getElementById("someId");`

You have edited your question.See you are passing a reference of an element to the function.
Your statement will return a reference to the parent of this element

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the function accepts an argument that is an element of some kind. The function first finds the parent of the element, and assigns it to a variable, fieldset.

It then fetches the value of the original element (whatyoutyped), and checks it against a regular expression. If the pattern matches, it changes the class of the parent element and sets 'compphone' to true. The syntax looks a bit weird though.

Without any context, it's difficult to say what this is for, but it seems to be checking some kind of input / text element against a regular expression - validation of some kind.

Comment: its for a form i just need to be able to explain to my lecture what "(whatyoutyped) means in English

Answer (score 0):

According to your other questions at SO, you have

```
<fieldset>
  <label for="Phone">Phone:</label>
  <input type="text" id="Phone" onkeyup="checkphone(this);" />
  <span class="hint">This Feld Must Be Numeric Values Only !</span>
</fieldset>
```

the (this) is passing the input field object to the function and the function looks at the parentNode of it which is the `<fieldset>` above it who's class is then set to nothing or welldone - I suggest you change *whatyoutyped* to *inputField*, for example so it makes more sense.

When you define a function, the word(s) you put in the () of the function will be the name(s) of the variable(s) passed to the function. so

```
function foo(bar) {
  alert(bar);
}
```

will alert Hello if you call it like this `foo("Hello")`

in your case you have

```
function checkphone(whateverYouWantToCallThePhoneFieldObjectInTheFunction) {
  do something with whateverYouWantToCallThePhoneFieldObjectInTheFunction
}
```

and can change it to something more readable:

```
function checkphone(inputField) {
  do something with inputField
}
```

and still pass it using

```
<input onblur="checkphone(this)"
```

since this is how to pass the object in its own event handlers